# React won't let me use my audio player and my game app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple question (hope it's simple). I made an app with React using Canvas, making a tower defense game. On top of the tower defense game, I also added in an audio player. But the issue I'm running into is whenever I press the anything in the audio player, I can't place anymore towers into the game.

For example, I get the app booted up, game starts, enemy starts coming out, I place a tower down. Then I go down to press play on the audio player to start playing music. After doing so, I bring my mouse up to the game board, but I can't place any towers down and my mouse is not tracking on the game board.

It's a long code, but here is the repo:
https://github.com/hongssam9/The-Great-Journey

You can try test it out on gitpages:
https://hongssam9.github.io/The-Great-Journey/